# How can i select block on what is clicked without reacting with others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an little issue with Jquery / Javascript. I have few blocks with same class name "item" and I need to do a function for just that one, that was clicked.

```
$(".item").click(function(){
 $(".item").animate({"margin:0px 80px"});
});
```

Actually I using this. But when I click on any element (item) they all doing this animaton.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
 $(this).animate({margin: "0px 80px"});
});
```

The difference with your code is that I'm using `this` to reference the element that fired the event. This is the standard behavior in jQuery event handlers.

Check this jQuery guide: [Inside the Event Handling Function](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/). You will find lots of useful guides there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".item").click(function(){
 $(this).animate({"margin:0px 80px"});
});
```